# FrameLayout height not matching parent

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have the following layout as custom view in AlertDialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:columnCount="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/code1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="\u2022"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_digit_size"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/code2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="\u2022"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_digit_size"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/code3"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="\u2022"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_digit_size"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/k1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_button_text"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/k2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_button_text"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/k3"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_button_text"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/k4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_button_text"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/k5"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_button_text"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/k6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:text="6"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_button_text"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/k7"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:text="7"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_button_text"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/k8"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:text="8"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_button_text"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/k9"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_button_text"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/k0"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_code_button_size"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="@dimen/match_code_button_text"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </GridLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/error"
            style="@style/ErrorText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/match_error"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#80ffffff"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Sorry for large volume of layout, put it here 'as is'.

Pay attention to the bottom FrameLayout with id **progress**. Despite it has **android:layout_height="match_parent"**, on the device it looks like "wrap_content" - has height only matching inner ProgressBar.
Though in Android Studio designer shown perfectly, occupying whole the view.

What's wrong?

Here is how layout looks in AS designer

[image: AS designer]

and on the device (tried both emulator and real device, the same effect)

[image: Device]

Comment: can you post a picture and expected output as well

Comment: add gravity to your child frame layout

Comment: @Alexey check my answer

Comment: @Alexey my answer should definitely help!

Answer (score 4):

Try to change the root FrameLayout to RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

You have two FrameLayouts.  @id *progress* one and a `LinearLayout` one.

First a quick look at the [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
>   a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single
>   child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a
>   way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children
>   overlapping each other.

So for your parent `FrameLayout` How many children you have?(2)

> You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control
>   their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each
>   child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

Is there any gravity in your both children? No not for the @id progress

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child
>   on top. The size of the FrameLayout is the size of its largest child
>   (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits).

So first you add linear layout and then you add FrameLayout so..  child `FrameLayout`  should be on top and it is. That's your issue right?

Even your layout is long in can be shorten to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#121"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#567"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Output** (i added an image for linear layout you are missing **gravity** in your *child* frame layout):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it. Seems like nobody noticed that but the source of your problem is a `GridLayout`. As you can see in the blueprint there is no problem with `FrameLayout` as it is indeed matching the parent. The items of your `GridLayout` have a fixed size and that is wrong. You need to set the weights for every item in the `GridLayout` so that the items can stretch to fit any screen resolution. But weights in `GridLayout` need API 21. So i suggest you use nested `LinearLayout's` with item's weights set to 1.

Comment: Nope, have tried with set of LinearLayout instead of GridLayout - the same problem :(

Comment: Did you set the width and height of items as fixed or with weights?

Comment: What i am trying to say is you should not use the dimensions from `dimen` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had on my project is, I had two Frame layouts with the same Id. 
The solution is to assign unique ids to frame layouts.

Hope this helps future readers.